# Adobe AIR and device compatibility

Tags: air, smartphone

I am a novice android app developer and I am starting to do some tests in Adobe Flash and then publish with Adobe AIR.

I have a question regarding compatiblity: I tried to test my application in a Samsung Ace smartphone and I couldn't because AIR is not supported. In a Toshiba Thrive, which supports AIR, it worked fine. I don't understand this: does this mean that when I eventually publish my app in Google Play, only certain people will be able to install it?

How come certain apps, like Angry Birds, were made in flash and they work in every smartphone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angry Birds only uses Flash for the Facebook version. I believe iOS and Android versions will be native.